# Android 6.0 Nexus 6 Crash in Adreno 420 driver

Tags: android, crash, opengl-es-2.0, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using `OpenGL` shared context for several `GLSurfaceView`. After switching from one activity to another the adreno driver is crashing. But my app is working well on other devices. Also, it works if I replace shared context with normal context. Is it bug in the driver?

Here's crash log:

```
11-03 14:03:39.358: A/libc(7900): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20c in tid 8012 (GLThread 1247)
11-03 14:03:39.460: A/DEBUG(1596): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-03 14:03:39.460: A/DEBUG(1596): Build fingerprint: 'google/shamu/shamu:6.0/MRA58K/2256973:user/release-keys'
11-03 14:03:39.460: A/DEBUG(1596): Revision: '0'
11-03 14:03:39.460: A/DEBUG(1596): ABI: 'arm'
11-03 14:03:39.461: A/DEBUG(1596): pid: 7900, tid: 8012, name: GLThread 1247  >>> com.example.app <<<
11-03 14:03:39.461: A/DEBUG(1596): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20c
11-03 14:03:39.484: A/DEBUG(1596):     r0 00000000  r1 27006880  r2 00000032  r3 9c35c000
11-03 14:03:39.484: A/DEBUG(1596):     r4 994d1640  r5 9e1c5d40  r6 00000000  r7 00000001
11-03 14:03:39.484: A/DEBUG(1596):     r8 9965155c  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp 9e14b394
11-03 14:03:39.485: A/DEBUG(1596):     ip 00000000  sp 9e33f1a0  lr a936efd3  pc a935acd6  cpsr 60010030
11-03 14:03:39.505: A/DEBUG(1596): backtrace:
11-03 14:03:39.505: A/DEBUG(1596):     #00 pc 0015dcd6  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xSamplerObject::UpdateRegs()+25)
11-03 14:03:39.505: A/DEBUG(1596):     #01 pc 00171fcf  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::ValidateTexSamplersCommon(A4xProgram*, int, EsxBitField96*)+490)
11-03 14:03:39.505: A/DEBUG(1596):     #02 pc 0017226b  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::ValidateTexSamplers()+66)
11-03 14:03:39.506: A/DEBUG(1596):     #03 pc 001707e1  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::ValidateState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+1596)
11-03 14:03:39.506: A/DEBUG(1596):     #04 pc 00170baf  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::HwValidateGfxState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+6)
11-03 14:03:39.506: A/DEBUG(1596):     #05 pc 000e731b  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::ValidateGfxState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+470)
11-03 14:03:39.506: A/DEBUG(1596):     #06 pc 000dc865  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::DrawElementsInstanced(EsxPrimType, unsigned int, EsxPixType, void const*, unsigned int)+432)
11-03 14:03:39.507: A/DEBUG(1596):     #07 pc 000c6ed3  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlDrawElements(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, void const*)+54)
11-03 14:03:39.507: A/DEBUG(1596):     #08 pc 000bd481  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glDrawElements+44)
11-03 14:03:39.507: A/DEBUG(1596):     #09 pc 000e6e2d  /data/app/com.example.app-1/lib/arm/librender.so (Render::quad()+324)
11-03 14:03:39.508: A/DEBUG(1596):     #17 pc 016abacd  /data/app/com.example.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0xa6e000) (boolean com.example.app.common.render.GLRenderer.onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)+88)
11-03 14:03:39.508: A/DEBUG(1596):     #18 pc 016a875b  /data/app/com.example.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0xa6e000) (void com.example.app.common.render.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun()+5590)
11-03 14:03:39.508: A/DEBUG(1596):     #19 pc 016aa1e9  /data/app/com.example.app-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0xa6e000) (void com.example.app.common.render.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run()+308)
11-03 14:03:39.509: A/DEBUG(1596):     #20 pc 000e6331  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
11-03 14:03:39.509: A/DEBUG(1596):     #21 pc 0040254d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+188)
11-03 14:03:39.509: A/DEBUG(1596):     #22 pc 00102774  [stack:8012]
```

Comment: The same issue for me

Comment: have you reported this bug to AOSP?

Comment: Reported https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216265